# AWS Route 53 with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

Currently I have many AWS Lambda deployed already. And then I think of how to perform Performance Test for each of AWS Lambda. The solution I decided to go is
- Expose each API using AWS Api Gateway for each AWS Lambda
- Use JMeter (Neoload) to perform "performance test" for an API.

The approach is working fine except we need to use a generated endpoint from AWS like https://tl8drdruob.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev. Now I would like to see if we can use Route 53 to route API or not.

We do have an host zone like abc.awsnonprod.mycompany.net. And I trying to add a record set to that host zone but I don't see any my API Gateway end points listing on Alias Target (API Gateway).

Please advice me if I missing something here.

Thank you

Comment: Here are formal instructions but I have the same problem that the end points aren't listing when creating a record ... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html

Answer (score 7):

It seems you need to have the custom domain name to map the route 53 to API Gateway.

Please follow [Set Up a Custom Domain Name for an API in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)

The API Gateway custom domain feature is very likely what you want. It will create a special/internal Cloudfront distribution which you can use to manipulate the domain and path. You can even relate it to API Gateway stages. Then you could use Route 53 to CNAME or A (alias) your custom domain to the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Is that the only way?